# MVC 4.5 Async Ajax call not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I have a slow running action on a controller that I've converted to the new Async method. It now runs much faster, however any jQuery Ajax calls to it return the following string,

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]
```

instead of waiting for the async to complete.

What am I doing wrong here? I've followed every example I can find and this isn't rocket science to implement.

Pretty much followed what is outlined in this video

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2287

And this link too

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4#CreatingAsynchGizmos

I understand that the Async doesn't change HTTP, but what I was expecting was for the long runnning Ajax call to work in the background, and then return to the user the result when it was finished. This would then free up the server to process additional ajax calls instead of blocking them.

Update:

Here is the javascript code

```
function doWork(options){
    return $.ajax("/getData", {
                    contentType: 'text/json',
                    async: true,
                    success: $.proxy(options.callback, options.scope),
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
                        options.callback.apply(options.scope, [error, textStatus, jqXHR]);
                    }
                });
}
```

And here is my controller action in C#

```
[HttpGet]
[AsyncTimeout(60000)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetData()
        {
            RestResponse<Data> response = new RestResponse<Data>();

            try
            {
                Data result = null;

                await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    result = ServerImpl.RetrieveData();
                });

                response.Value = result;
                response.HttpStatusCode = 200;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.HttpStatusCode = 500;
                response.Value = null;
            }

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Session in your controller action?

Comment: Then that's your problem. The ASP.NET Session doesn't allow you to perform parallel requests from the same session. Since the ASP.NET Session is not thread safe, ASP.NET will simply block concurrent access to the server from the same session and make them wait and execute sequentially. The ASP.NET Session introduces state and many other problems in your application and it is a design smell. If you want to have a scalable and stateless application the first thing you should do is to get rid of it.

Comment: @Darin Thanks for your help. We're going to try and change our architecture around this. I'm surprised at how difficult it is to find information on this. If you submit an answer I'd be more than happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that your server side action uses ASP.NET Session which is characterized by not being thread-safe. As a consequence, ASP.NET queues parallel requests from the same session and executes them sequentially. Having a RESTful API relying on session is a very bad design and IMHO should be rearchitectured so that it doesn't rely on state.

Comment: I think to have the same problem. But I don't understand how to disable session. I have already disabled in web.config but the task is still not resolved.

Answer (score 3):

I think I had the same problem where using Session was preventing my requests running concurrently. Since I'm not modifying session already, decorating my controller with this attribute allows the requests to run concurrently now.
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]